# Does smtp in IIS refer to smtp service or smtp server?

Tags: iis, smtp

In control panel there is a option to turn on certain features that are not installed by default. When you turn on IIS feature it has an option called smtp email. Does it refer to smtp service or smtp server? I have looked for the answer. But there is no concrete answer. Some say it's a service others say it refers to server. Can anyone please help me with the confusion??

Answer (score 0):

The SMTP service under IIS is a simple relay agent. You really cannot use it as a mail server, as there is no real interface for retrieving (reading) emails from that service.

You typically use the SMTP service as a sending buffer for outgoing emails generated by your server (e.g. website). You configure the SMTP service as a relay for outgoing emails (e.g. to a smarthost) and then you can have your website generate emails to the local SMTP service. This way your website is not affected if network or other server problems would affect mail sending, as the SMTP service queues the emails you generate and can automatically retry deliveries etc.

Comment: Sorry..... But I am still not very clear about it. Can you please be more clear on your answer?

Comment: A server is a program that is always running that typically sits and waits for a client to connect to it and utilize whatever the server is providing. A service is way to keep a program running in the background. In this particular case, there is a separate SMTP service that functions as a relatively simple SMTP server, i.e. both service and server refer to the same thing. Is this clear enough or what do you need clarification on?

Comment: Thanks, So it is both service and server..... But if smtp service is not enabled by default then how is mail sent from the pc?? Because smtp is the default protocol through which any mail is sent.

Comment: When you send mail from the pc, your email program is contacting the smtp service in a mail server directly, so you do not need a local smtp server for that. A local smtp server can help if e.g. you are sending large amounts of mail and do not want to be directly dependent on an smtp server in another machine, as you can queue your mails locally and let the smtp server forward the emails.